# Client didn't communicate for majority of project timeline

Tags: freelance-websites, payments

I recently found my first freelancing project on [freelancer.com](http://freelancer.com). After I got the login credentials to edit a Joomla site and the first task from the employer, communication completely ceased. He was not online for three days, the project duration was only seven days, and today is the last day.

The employer has a good reputation on the website, but I don't have any reputation yet.

What should I do in such a case? Does this mean that I'm not going to get paid?

Comment: I don't use freelancer but here's their FAQ page. https://www.freelancer.com/faq/view.php You could also try talking to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to happen a lot when using freelancing websites. Have you got a business name or can you find a LinkedIn profile for your client? It may be worth trying to get in touch by other means.

You may also try emailing the customer support team at freelancer.com and explaining that you've had an unresponsive client. They may be able to chase them up too.

I'm sorry to say you may have to write this one off, and don't do any more work on it until you have a reply from them.

Comment: after 3 days(from this post) the client texted me and told me that he was sorry he had some professional issues ..etc and then he send the full payment despite the job is not finished (cause i need some informations so i can do it). but thank you for the answer , it does provide some information on what i should do if this happens another time.

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted and good news on getting your payment. Good luck in future jobs!